# How to apply custom css on fb:login-button?

Tags: jquery, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to apply custom my own CSS on facebook javascript sdk button.
I have used this below button for facebook login.

```
<fb:login-button id="fblogin" max-rows="1"  width="100px" size="xlarge" class="facebookbutton" scope="public_profile,email" show-faces="false" onlogin="fbLogin();">
                                    Sign up with Facebook
  </fb:login-button>

I have applied CSS like below but this not apply on facebook button.

#fblogin{
width:100% !important;
color:Green !important; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Step 1: Include the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript) on your page once, ideally right after the opening body tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.2&appId=yourID&autoLogAppEvents=1"></script>
```

Step 2: Place this code wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="false"></div>
```

[Source page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/)